# want to set a self var using guard statement

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code, where I'm trying to set a self variable (self?.users) from a view model call. The code snippet looks like this.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        self?.model?.findAll() { [weak self] users, exception in // network call
            guard users != nil, self?.users = users else { // Optional type ()? cannot be used as a boolean; test for !=nil instead
                
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

1. I'm capturing [weak self] twice, is that okay?, can I capture it once as weak in the enclosing closure?
2. Should I use this instead of guard statement?

---

```
self?.model?.findAll() { [weak self] users, exception in
    if exception != nil {
        self?.users = users
    }
}
```

Comment: The following is unnecessary.  DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in }

Comment: `DispatchQueue.global().async` houses `findAll` which is a network call, is it unnecessary?

Comment: Sorry, I mean [weak self]

Comment: if i remove [weak self] from outer closure, it gives error for this line -> `self?.model?.findAll`, no issue if i remove it from inner closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles so capture lists are not necessary.

Something like this, to avoid confusion I'd recommend to rename the incoming users and the code to reload the table view must be inside the closure

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.model?.findAll() { [weak self] foundUsers, exception in // network call
            guard let foundUsers = foundUsers else { return }  
            self?.users = foundUsers
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And don’t forget to call `super`